# how to display 2D array in gridlayout

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have `Array [] [] myArray = new Array [5] [5]`, or `Array [] [] myArray = new Array [7] [9]`, or `new Array  [12] [13]`

I want to display the array in `GridLayout`.
I found many examples but there is not a 2D array.

Tell me I should extend `BaseAdapter`? 
I do not know about how to solve this problem

Comment: An adapter will be useless for a `GridLayout` as it isn't a child of  `AdapterView` and it can't use it. What kind of layout are you trying to do? Is it just a table to replicate that 2D array(in which case a `TableLayout` might be an option)? Do you absolutely require a `Gridlayout`?

Comment: Me any of the examples that will display to an array of table

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment. Do you want an example displaying a 2D array using a `TableLayout`? Or?

Comment: problem, show 2D array on the screen programmatically, I do not care how

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing you can do is, you can convert 2D array to a simple 1D array (using a for loop) and proceed as usual. And if you need to set the items dynamically (I mean, if you do not know the dimensions of the array before hand), then you have use the setColumnCount() to set the number of columns you need (5,9,13 in your examples). You don't have to wo0rry about the number rows as Android takes care of the rows. And yes, you should use BaseAdapter.

Comment: can be an example for the second option?

Comment: You mean you want an example for this? If yes, http://mytelcoit.com/2010/02/programming-android-create-icon-with-text-using-gridview-and-layout-inflater/

Comment: Also, you have to be careful. If you are doing this for learning, then its ok. If you are doing this for some project, then having a large column value is not advised as one column may overlap on another.

Comment: yes but this example does not show the implementation 2D array